# Spark job failing while writing to aws s3 bucket -

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3

Spark job failing while writing to aws s3 bucket and I am getting java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory

Stack Trace:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory: s3a://vishal/test/abc.parquet/_temporary/0/task_20190422091705_0001_m_000000 
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:993) 
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.listStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:734) 
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.mergePaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:360) 
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:310) 
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputCommitter.commitJob(ParquetOutputCommitter.java:48) 
at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:166) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:185) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:159) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155) 
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:668) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:668) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:668) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:276) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:270) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:228) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:557)
```

Comment: Could you provide source code as well please.

Comment: Dataset<Row> data = spark.read().format("jdbc")
      .option("url",(url)
      .option("user", user)
      .option("password", password)
      .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
      .option("dbtable", fetchQuery).load().
      withColumn("ID",  functions.col("ID").cast(t)).
      withColumn("VOLUME",  functions.col("VOLUME").cast(t));

data.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).partitionBy("DATE").parquet(s3path);

Comment: @VishalGor please edit your question and add source code to it.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably a permission issue. From you exception it looks like Spark job is lacking AWS S3 permission to `GetObject`. Make sure your Spark Job have at least Read,Write and Move permissions.

But if you are writing to a S3 location using Spark and expecting that file to immediately available for Spark then its not going to work every time because

> S3 may take time for a newly created object to appear in directory listings, while deleted objects may still be visible.

If you still need to do this I would suggest perform all file related operation on a reliable persistent storage like local (i.e. disk or HDFS) once your file is final move it to S3.

But if you not left with any other option try [S3Guard](https://medium.com/opendoor-labs/why-we-use-s3guard-with-s3-as-a-filesystem-for-spark-6cf464f8bacd).

Comment: It works many times only once in a while I am getting this exception. If I run again it works,